# Continuous function in any segment of interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous at any segment $[c,d]$ where $a<c<d<b$. It it true that $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$?

How to prove or refute this claim strictly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true: Continuity is a local principle, i.e. it suffices to check it in arbitrary small neighbourhoods of points. Since $(a,b)$ is an open interval, every point $x\in(a,b)$ lies in an interval of the form $x\in[c,d]$ with $c\neq x\neq d$. Hence the continuity of $f$ on $[c,d]$ implies the continuity of $f$ at the arbitrary point $x\in (a,b)$ and we see that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear mathmax! Great answer!